# Custom datalist - options disappear before selection

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-events, html-datalist

I've prepared the following code for a live search. On input focus, a list of available options appear. On input blur, options disappear. There lies my problem. When you click on an item form the list, input loses the focus and the list disappears before the click event takes place.

```js
var artists = [{"artist":"3 Doors Down"},{"artist":"5 Seconds of Summer"},{"artist":"Adele"},{"artist":"Alicia Keys"},{"artist":"Amanda Abizaid"}];

function liveSearch(element) {
  return new liveSearch.prototype.init(element);
}
liveSearch.prototype = {
  init : function(element) {
    if (!element) {
      this.element = document.createElement("ul");
      this.element.classList.add("liveSearch");
    } else {
      this.element = element;
    }
  },
  update : function(queryElement) {
    this.clear();
    var lookUpArray = queryElement.name + "s";
    var results = this.search(artists, queryElement.value, queryElement.name);
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      var value = results[i];
      if (queryElement.value != "") {
        var re = new RegExp(queryElement.value, "gi");
        value = value.replace(re, "<span class=\"highlight\">" + "$&" + "</span>");
      }
      li.innerHTML = value;
      this.element.appendChild(li);
    }
    return results.length;
  },
  search : function(lookUpArray, string) {
    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < lookUpArray.length; i++) {
      if (lookUpArray[i].artist.toLowerCase().search(string.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
        results.push(lookUpArray[i].artist);
      }
    }
    return results;
  },
  clear : function() {
    this.element.innerHTML = "";
  },
  hidden : function() {
    this.element.style.display = "none";
  },
  visible : function() {
    this.element.style.display = "";
  },
  remove : function() {
    this.element.parentElement.removeChild(this.element);
  },
};
liveSearch.prototype.init.prototype = liveSearch.prototype;

$("#lyrics-form").on("focus", "input.liveSearch-input", function() {
  this.parentElement.appendChild(liveSearch().element);
  if (liveSearch(this.nextElementSibling).update(this)) {
    liveSearch(this.nextElementSibling).visible();
  } else {
    liveSearch(this.nextElementSibling).hidden();
  }
});

$("#lyrics-form").on("blur", "input.liveSearch-input", function() {
  liveSearch(this.nextElementSibling).remove();
});

$("#lyrics-form").on("keyup", "input.liveSearch-input", function() {
  if (this.value != "") {
    if (liveSearch(this.nextElementSibling).update(this)) {
      liveSearch(this.nextElementSibling).visible();
    } else {
      liveSearch(this.nextElementSibling).hidden();
    }
  } else {
    liveSearch(this.nextElementSibling).update(this);
  }
});

$("#lyrics-form").on("click", "li", function() {
  this.parentElement.previousElementSibling.value = this.innerText;
  liveSearch(this.parentElement).hidden();
});
```

```css
input, ul {
  width: 180px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.liveSearch {
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px;
  max-height: 195px;
  width: 180px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.liveSearch li {
  padding: 2px 5px;
  cursor: default;
}
.liveSearch li:hover {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  color: black;
}
.liveSearch .highlight {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="addlyrics.php" id="lyrics-form" method="post" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="text" name="artist" id="artist" class="liveSearch-input" placeholder="Artist" required />
</form>
```

I've used a timeout on blur to get around the problem, but it's not good enough. It's not consistent, and higher delays makes the design ugly. How can I fix this?

```
$("#lyrics-form").on("blur", "input.liveSearch-input", function() {
    /* liveSearch(this.nextElementSibling).remove(); */
    setTimeout(function() {
        liveSearch(this.nextElementSibling).remove();
    }.bind(this), 100);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just learned about the `datalist` element. It kinda does what I'm trying to accomplish here, but I can't style it, or modify it. So I've made some changes to my code and made a custom datalist.

```js
var artists = [{"artist":"3 Doors Down"},{"artist":"5 Seconds of Summer"},{"artist":"Adele"},{"artist":"Alicia Keys"},{"artist":"Amanda Abizaid"}];

function datalist(element) {
  return new datalist.prototype.init(element);
}
datalist.prototype = {
  init : function(element) {
    if (!element) {
      this.element = document.createElement("ul");
      this.element.classList.add("datalist");;
      this.hide();
    } else {
      this.element = element;
    }
  },
  update : function(queryElement) {
    this.clear();
    var lookUpArray = queryElement.name + "s";
    var results = this.search(window[lookUpArray], queryElement.value, queryElement.name);
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
      var li = document.createElement("li");
      var value = results[i][queryElement.name];
      if (queryElement.value != "") {
        var re = new RegExp(queryElement.value, "gi");
        value = value.replace(re, "<span class=\"highlight\">" + "$&" + "</span>");
      }
      li.innerHTML = value;
      this.element.appendChild(li);
    }
    return results.length;
  },
  search : function(lookUpArray, string, queryType) {
    var results = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < lookUpArray.length; i++) {
      if (lookUpArray[i][queryType].toLowerCase().search(string.toLowerCase()) != -1) {
        results.push(lookUpArray[i]);
      }
    }
    return results;
  },
  clear : function() {
    this.element.innerHTML = "";
  },
  hide : function() {
    this.element.style.display = "none";
  },
  show : function() {
    this.element.style.display = "";
  },
  remove : function() {
    this.element.parentElement.removeChild(this.element);
  },
};
datalist.prototype.init.prototype = datalist.prototype;

var lastVisitedInput = null;

$("#lyrics-form").on("focus", "input.datalist-input", function() {
  if (this.parentElement.children.length == 1) {
    this.parentElement.appendChild(datalist().element);
  }
  if (lastVisitedInput) {
    datalist(lastVisitedInput.nextElementSibling).hide();
  }
  lastVisitedInput = this;
  if (datalist(this.nextElementSibling).update(this)) {
    datalist(this.nextElementSibling).show();
  }
});

$("#lyrics-form").on("input", "input.datalist-input", function() {
  datalist(this.nextElementSibling).update(this);
});

$(document).on("click", function(e) {
  if (lastVisitedInput) {
    var exceptions = getExceptions(lastVisitedInput);
    if (!contains(exceptions, e.target)) {
      datalist(lastVisitedInput.nextElementSibling).remove();
      lastVisitedInput = null;
    }
  }
});

$("#lyrics-form").on("click", "li", function() {
  this.parentElement.previousElementSibling.value = this.innerText;
  $(this.parentElement.previousElementSibling).trigger("input");
});

function getExceptions(input) {
  var exceptions = [
    input,
    input.nextElementSibling,
  ];
    for (var i = 0; i < input.nextElementSibling.children.length; i++) {
    exceptions.push(input.nextElementSibling.children[i]);
}
return exceptions;
}

function contains(array, item) {
  for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    if (array[i] === item) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}
```

```css
input {
  padding: 5px;
}
input, ul {
  width: 200px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.datalist {
  margin: 0;
  border: 1px solid silver;
  box-shadow: 0 2px 5px rgba(0,0,0,.5);
  position: absolute;
  background: white;
  padding: 5px;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  z-index: 1000;
}
.datalist li {
  padding: 2px 5px;
  cursor: default;
}
.datalist li:hover {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,.05);
  color: black;
}
.datalist .highlight {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="lyrics-form" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
 <input type="search" name="artist" id="artist" class="datalist-input" placeholder="Artist" required />
</form>
```

Comment: The entire list disappears once an item has been selected. I found this to be the case everytime I try to use datalist  (Chrome Version 63.0.3239.84 (Official Build) (64-bit))

Comment: @Rid I don't think that's a bug, because as you type into the box, it filters the list items and returns the matched items. If you click on the box after a selection, it will treat it as you've typed something and it has returned matching item(s).

Comment: you're probably right, but I find this counter intuitive and I know for sure I can't present it like that to our user base.